# create a new column with a given initial value

Tags: r, dplyr

I want to create a new column giving it an initial value ***G*** followed by the square root of **2 * *G***.

I think the ***dplyr* package** would be *suitable*.

```
mutate (df, newcol = )
```

In *MS Excel*, for *column B*, it would be something like, **G*, B2*sqrt(2), B3*sqrt(2) and so on*.  Now I want to do it in **R**. Any help/comment is appreciated.

Comment: Can you add a small reproducible example along with expected output?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to specify the column and the logic of the formula you want to apply:

```
data<- data.frame(Col1 = 1:10)
data %>% mutate(Col2 = sqrt(2)**Col1)
      Col1      Col2
1     1  1.414214
2     2  2.000000
3     3  2.828427
4     4  4.000000
5     5  5.656854
6     6  8.000000
7     7 11.313708
8     8 16.000000
9     9 22.627417
10   10 32.000000
```

Following @Ronak logic, you can also do `cumprod()` as follows:

```
data<- data.frame(Col1 = rep(sqrt(2),10))
data %>% mutate(Col2 = cumprod(Col1))
       Col1      Col2
1  1.414214  1.414214
2  1.414214  2.000000
3  1.414214  2.828427
4  1.414214  4.000000
5  1.414214  5.656854
6  1.414214  8.000000
7  1.414214 11.313708
8  1.414214 16.000000
9  1.414214 22.627417
10 1.414214 32.000000
```

Comment: Thank you for this. Is it possible to create just Col2 giving an initial value 1.41 and followed by multiplication with sqrt(2) so that values are 1.99, 2.82, 3.99...

Comment: I have reedited my answer for you to see a couple of ways of doing it

Answer (score 2):

I think you are looking for cumulative product

```
df$b <- cumprod(df$b)

# a        b
#1 a 1.414214
#2 b 2.000000
#3 c 2.828427
#4 d 4.000000
#5 e 5.656854
```

---

Or if you want to do something more complicated use `Reduce` with your custom function

```
Reduce(`*`, df$b, accumulate = TRUE)
#[1] 1.414214 2.000000 2.828427 4.000000 5.656854
```

**data**

```
df <- data.frame(a = letters[1:5])
df$b <- sqrt(2)
```